# Justify-content not applied to the flex-container as a whole

Tags: html, css

Let's suppose I am building a simple to-do list. Here's the HTML code and the CSS code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Lista de Coisas a Fazer</title>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom Style -->

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Unna&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- FontAwesome Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    
</head><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style copia.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="intro col-12">
      <h1>To-do List</h1>           
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="instrucoes">
      <p id="first">- lorem ipsum;</p>
      <p id="second">- lorme ipsum;</p>
      <p id="third">- lorem ipsu;.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <input id="userInput" type="text" placeholder="New item..." maxlength="27">
      <button id="enter"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="listItems col-12">
      <ul class="col-12 offset-0 col-sm-8 offset-sm-2">

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
<script  src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's the CSS script so far:

```
body, html {

    background: rgb(200,218,211);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(200,218,211,1) 0%, rgba(242,246,245,1) 100%);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;

}


.row {

    justify-content: center;
}
```

My question is: why is the `justify-content` attribute of `body` and `HTML` not applying automatically to the `.row` class?

If I delete the `justify-content` of the `".row"` class, only the first `.row` element (the To-Do List `h1`) it's aligned in the center. As far as I know, the `justify-content` attribute of the flex display should be applied to all child elements of the flex-container (in this case the `body` and `HTML`). Am I wrong here? Why do I have to set up individual `justify-content` attributes to all `.row` elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, you had an incorrect html code. There was an extra closing `div` tag after the `container` class. I corrected your html. And now all the `row` is inside the `container` class. To center your elements, create this selector below.

```
.container .row .col-12 {
     flex: unset;
     width: auto;
}
```

The problem was the `flex: 0 0 100%` rule preventing your items from being centered. And also, the `width: auto` be set. Hope this is what you need.

...and the above rules apply ONLY to the `col-12` class that is inside the `row` class.

```css
body, html {

    background: rgb(200,218,211);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(200,218,211,1) 0%, rgba(242,246,245,1) 100%);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;

}


.row {
    justify-content: center;
}

.container .row .col-12 {
     flex: unset;
     width: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Lista de Coisas a Fazer</title>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom Style -->

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Unna&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- FontAwesome Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    
</head><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style copia.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="intro col-12">
      <h1>To-do List</h1>           
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="instrucoes">
      <p id="first">- lorem ipsum;</p>
      <p id="second">- lorme ipsum;</p>
      <p id="third">- lorem ipsu;.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <input id="userInput" type="text" placeholder="New item..." maxlength="27">
      <button id="enter"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="listItems col-12">
      <ul class="col-12 offset-0 col-sm-8 offset-sm-2">

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script  src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

justify-content should be applied to a container with display: flex; your .row class was trying to tell its children to align to the center but it was not a flex container. so the children did not listen and stayed aligned to the left.

```css
body, html {

    background: rgb(200,218,211);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(200,218,211,1) 0%, rgba(242,246,245,1) 100%);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;

}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.row {
   display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Lista de Coisas a Fazer</title>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom Style -->

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Unna&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- FontAwesome Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    
</head><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style copia.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="intro col-12">
      <h1>To-do List</h1>           
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="instrucoes">
      <p id="first">- lorem ipsum;</p>
      <p id="second">- lorme ipsum;</p>
      <p id="third">- lorem ipsu;.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 row">
      <input id="userInput" type="text" placeholder="New item..." maxlength="27">
      <button id="enter"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="listItems col-12">
      <ul class="col-12 offset-0 col-sm-8 offset-sm-2">

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
<script  src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```